# how to upper a column with collate in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, collate

We are doing an integration between two software, I am trying to convert a column to uppercase in select statement but Turkish characters get converted wrong. Iknow to use "collate" in where clause but can I use it in "select upper(col1) from ..."

here is how I use collate it in "where"

```
WHERE Column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'casesearch'
```

but I dont know how to use it in

```
select upper(col1) from ...
```

can anybody give me a clue?

Comment: select upper(col1 COLLATE somecollation) ?

Comment: Would you care to add some examples of text that gets converted wrong, and what the right conversion ought to be?

Comment: i know its late but this example might help someone                
`UPPER(CAST(COLUMNNAME COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC277_2_CP1_CS_AS AS VARCHAR(255) ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [@Ömer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6124847/%C3%96mer) had given the answer in the comments. I just quoted from him. Credits belong to him.

Tested and worked.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TheTable
WHERE
    UPPER(CAST(Column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS AS VARCHAR(255))) = UPPER(CAST('casesearch' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS AS VARCHAR(255))))
```

Or for just select expression:

```
SELECT
    UPPER(CAST(Column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS AS VARCHAR(255)))
FROM
    TheTable
```